# svn+ssh isn't work by using user svn

Tags: svn

I had installed subversion and managed it allow only user who have key in authorized_keys of svn. There is a weird thing when I'm working around with ssv+ssh.

the svn is working when I use below;

> **svn info svn+ssh://server1/repos/test**

but it shown no repositories when I use this;

> **svn info svn+ssh://svn@server1/repos/test**

My questions;

1. What is different between these above command? and
2. How to make the second command work with the same result of the first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- With `svn+ssh://server1/` you'll login to remote server under local (see `whoami`) username
- With `svn+ssh://svn@server1/` you'll login to remote server under user `svn` name, which be not SVN-capable user, check `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of this user, `command=` content